# Should std::async be called in a game loop c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

How efficient is the call to std::async? Can it be used to issue a task in a game loop?

I want all my input detection to be on a separate thread and synced at a certain point in the game loop in my main thread so that I can poll for input.

The only way I can think of doing this is to split up my tasks for input detection and call them using `std::async` at the beginning of the actual game loop and then call `wait()` later in the loop to sync the data, but I want that same behavior EVERY iteration of the loop so this call must be expensive...

Is that the way?

Comment: Might be better to use a thread pool of some sort to handle the asynchronous tasks?

Comment: the question is somehow a little bit encrypted, "async" it's more like a paradigm rather than something that can be measured in terms of performance. The point of an async approach is to create and manage a queue of relatively small tasks with no guarantee about the starting time and the finish time. If you have a shop and you assign a task to an employee for managing a queue there is no connection between this and how much your shop will sell or how many people will be in your queue, there is just 1 person that is in charge of the queue management, that's all you can say about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's well written then `std::async(std::launch::async, ...)` should be no more expensive than a small heap allocation and constructing a `std::thread`.  If creating a new `std::thread` to do the work is efficient enough for you, then `std::async` will be efficient enough but will save you the trouble of writing the synchronisation to get the result back to the main thread.

If creating a new `std::thread` for each piece of work is not appropriate, then `std::async` might not be either.

(N.B. remember that unless you specify `std::launch::async` as the launch policy there's no guarantee the task executes asynchronously, it might be deferred until you call `get()` on the returned future.)

Answer (score 3):

At least IMO, you should make up your mind between polling and asynchronous operation.

If you're going to poll, then using `std::async` is redundant. You're going to poll from the main thread anyway, so you might as well just have it directly poll for what it cares about and be done with it. Using `std::async` to launch something else will simply add a delay in getting the data to the main thread.

If you're going to use `std::async`, then you should take a rather different approach: the threads that get the input act independently. When they find some input, they send it to the main thread, and tell it that it has some input to process (e.g., by setting a semaphore). Then the main thread reacts to that semaphore, retrieves the input data (e.g., from a queue) and processes it.

In the latter case, polling is pointless: if the input thread hasn't told the main thread about some input data, then there simply isn't any. That being the case, polling for input data is pointless -- you already know there is none.